# Shouldn't we merge russian.stackexchange.com and rus.stachexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-merging

I am actually a moderator for http://russian.stackexchange.com and today I was kinda surprised to find a second Russian-language dedicated beta which I have no idea to exist - http://rus.stackexchange.com.

There are two reasons for me being surprised. First, if you search area51 by word "Русский" ("Russian") you won't find nothing. If you will search by word rus you won't find Rus SE as well, only Russian SE.

Second, the only difference between Russian and Rus is that on Russian SE questions are asked - as well as answers are given -  in both Russian and English, as opposed to Rus SE which is sort of Russian only.

To my experience all language dedicated SE sites are bilingual by and that is, in my opinion is benificial for everyone. On the other hand, I need to acknowledge that the amount of users using Rus is impressive.

```
                Rus     Russian
               =====    =======

questions      7911      1,402
answers        17,290    3,964
answered       95%       100%
users          3,300     4,207
visitors/day   9,943     763
```

It looks like that if will merge this two very closely related stack into one it would be very good for Russian language dedicated community. It looks like it we would be way closer to getting out of beta.

**UPDATE:** I should note that Russian SE is **not** an analogue of [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) - it's exact analogue of English SE or French SE. This is crucial. One can take literally any question from Rus SE and it will be 100% relevant on Russian. User @m0nhawk is just wrong in his assumption.

Comment: I removed the [meta-tag:bug] tag - this is a request for discussion.

Comment: @Oded, there's a bug - 404 dead link that lead from Rus beta to dedicated area51 page. Why you've removed this tag? If you want I cancreate a separate post/bug report on this - because it is well, a bug.

Comment: That's a different thing from the *main* discussion of merging sites - you should open a new and different post for the bug. Putting more than one issue on a post just confuses matters for readers and those who answer.

Comment: And there is no Area 51 proposal for Rus (as you well know), so of course that dead ends.

Comment: @Oded - care to clarify please. I don't understant. I thought that if beta exists and there is a link to Area51 - the page should exists.

Comment: No, rus.se was not an Area 51 proposal. It was an import from the hashcode network (that was acquired by SE).

Comment: @Oded, Wasn't the import done on http://ru.stackoverflow.com? This is different from the Q/A site on http://rus.stackexchange.com. Or are you talking about another hashcode besides [*this* Hashcode](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104860/159916)?

Comment: @Pacerier - that's right. Hashcode was a *network* of sites - we only brought in a couple of them.

Answer (score 11):

These are two different sites for two different audiences.

- [Rus.SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) is used by Russian-speaking users to ask language-related questions about their native language.
- [Russian.SE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/) is used by English-speaking users to ask language-related questions about Russian language.

I would not recommend merging these sites, but renaming them is necessary, because "Rus" and "Russian" is a big source of confusion.

Comment: it just not true, Russian SE is used byt both Russian and English native speakers. There was no Rus.SE - it was acquired - this is the only reason that this site exists. No offense, but I can see that you haven't used Russian SE so far. I just don't understant how you can make such claims.

Comment: Yes, I didn't use Russian.SE, and neither Rus.SE. If I wasn't Russian-speaking user, then I would use _only_ Russian.SE. But as Russian-speaking user I use Rus.SE, because it is written in my native language (so I can understand it better).
Also, Rus.SE community is more active, because users don't have to know English there, and in Russian.SE they _have to_ because of the interface.

Comment: So, I think, that Rus.SE is Russian community about Russian language, and Russian.SE is English community about Russian language.